# How to query 3 entities that have references between them with an Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have 3 entities, where there is a reference between A and B, and another reference between B and C.

How can I query the data starting from entity A, where the result contains relevant data from entity B, and the same the result from entity B contains relevant data from entity C.

I was able to retrieve data between A and B using the following command:

```
context.A.Include(m => m.B).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.b_aid == aid);
```

where the result looks like:

```
{
    aid:1,
    B:[
       { bid:2, b_aid:1},
       { bid:3, b_aid:1}
      ]
}
```

I want to have the results to be something like:

```
{
    aid:1,
    B:[
       {
        bid:2, 
        b_aid:1,
        C: [
            {
              cid:1,
              c_bid:1
            }// end job1 of list C
          ]
       },// end obj1 of list B
       {
        bid:3, 
        b_aid:1,
        C: []
       } // end obj2 of list B
      ] // end B List
}
```

where the classes design like as follows:

```
class A 
{
    int aid;
    List<B> b;
}

class B
{
    int bid;
    List<C> c;

    [reference]
    int b_aid;
}

class C
{
    int cid;

    [reference]
    Int c_bid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
context.A
    .Include(a => a.b)
    .ThenInclude(b => b.c)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.b_aid == aid);
```